# Troubleshooting Nissan Maxima Headlights

Tags: nissan, troubleshooting, headlight, maxima

The headlights on my 2006 Nissan Maxima have been acting strange lately. I’ve found that when I turn on the headlights, only the fog lights will turn on. When I turn on the blinker though, the headlight on that side will turn on. I’m not very familiar with troubleshooting car electrical issues beyond replacing the fuses, battery, or bulbs. How do I go about troubleshooting something like this? It doesn’t seem to be something that can be caused by a blown fuse or a bad bulb.

Comment: Did the issue start to occur on both headlights at the same time?

Comment: @HandyHowie yes it did